# Mock, UnitTest, JSON

Tags: python, json, unit-testing

been having an issue with creating a unittest to make sure that the method that I'd like works well. Running it with nodetests though gave no coverage.

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock, patch, MagicMock
from django.conf import settings
from hackathon.scripts.steam import *


class SteamTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.API_URL = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/'
        self.APIKEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        self.userID = 'Marorin'
        self.steamnum = '76561197997115778'

    def testGetUserIDNum(self):
        '''Test for steam.py method'''

        # Pulling from setUp
        userID = self.userID
        API_URL = self.API_URL
        APIKEY = self.APIKEY   

        # constructing the URL
        self.url = API_URL + '?' + APIKEY + '&' + userID

        with patch('hackathon.scripts.steam.steamIDpulling') as mock_steamIDPulling:
            # Mocking the return value of this method.
            mock_steamIDpulling = 76561197997115778
            self.assertEqual(steamIDPulling(userID,APIKEY),mock_steamIDpulling)
```

Method in pulling information:

```
    def steamIDPulling(SteamUN,key): 
#Pulls out and returns the steam id number for use in steam queries. steaminfo = {'key': key,'vanityurl': SteamUN} 
a = requests.get('api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/';, params=steaminfo)
 k = json.loads(a.content) 
SteamID = k['response']['steamid'] 
return SteamID
```

Comment: Is this your actual API key in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Mocking the return value of this method.
mock_steamIDpulling = 76561197997115778
```

Should be:

```
# Mocking the return value of this method.
mock_steamIDpulling.return_value = 76561197997115778
```

However, you code does not really make sense. If you are trying to test the return value of `steamIDpulling`, just do:

```
def testGetUserIDNum(self):
    '''Test for steam.py method'''

    # Pulling from setUp
    userID = self.userID
    API_URL = self.API_URL
    APIKEY = self.APIKEY   

    # constructing the URL
    self.url = API_URL + '?' + APIKEY + '&' + userID
    self.assertEqual(steamIDPulling(userID,APIKEY), 76561197997115778)
```

Mocking is only needed if a value inside the tested method needs to be changed (unless your testing the `mock` library). To mock the request library, do:

```
def testGetUserIDNum(self):
    '''Test for steam.py method'''

    # Pulling from setUp
    userID = self.userID
    API_URL = self.API_URL
    APIKEY = self.APIKEY   

    # constructing the URL
    self.url = API_URL + '?' + APIKEY + '&' + userID
    with patch("requests.get") as mock_requests_get:
        mock_requests_get.return_value = """{"response": {"streamid":76561197997115778}}"""
        self.assertEqual(steamIDPulling(userID,APIKEY), 76561197997115778)
```

Comment: So it's not needed to mock the requests library then?

Comment: def steamIDPulling(SteamUN,key):
    #Pulls out and returns the steam id number for use in steam queries.
    steaminfo = {'key': key,'vanityurl': SteamUN}
    a = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/', params=steaminfo)
    k = json.loads(a.content)
    SteamID = k['response']['steamid']
    
    return SteamID

Comment: Code's also on the question.

Comment: and then I'd replace the second parameter of assertEqual with mock_requests_get.return_value right?

Comment: One more question: If I were to do this for another method but the output is a big Json, how would I be able to shrink the test code?

Comment: Apologies but it seems like nodetests isn't seeing that it's covered.

Comment: Are you sure the test is run? It might be worth asking a new question, as fitting all the information here might be tricky.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453277/nosetests-and-covering-on-scripts See this.