# Unit test fixtures in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I'm writing a library in Python which makes calls to a REST API, receives results in JSON, and returns Python class instances after transforming the results.

Is there a generally accepted way of including test fixtures (ie JSON files to test against) inside of the Python package and test namespace to load and test against in your test cases?

Comment: I would separate the function to 1) load JSON into dict and pass it to 2nd function, 2) convert dict to your python class. Then unittest would mainly focus on the 2nd function, and fixtures can be included as a dict in script.

Comment: Yes, I'll do the conversion to a Python map first, then the testing, but I want to test the actual structure.

Comment: In the case, I would try embed the json-file as string and rely on [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) for unittest.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the mock module. and mock the request.get  like in this post [Mock, UnitTest, JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442296/mock-unittest-json)

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, but I want to test on the actual expected JSON to make sure my parsing works for it.

Comment: So are you saying you want to test your json parser that is now another method

Comment: Parsing the JSON isn't my concern, I'll use a library which contains its own unit tests for that, my main concern is working with the actual data structure.